# Pointing Python in Ubutnu to 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Python 3.7 in Ubuntu 18.04. Now as Ubuntu is written in Python 3.6, there are many applications that explicitly point to Python3 (which in my case is now 3.7). Is there any way I can explicitly make them point to 3.6 instead of default Python3

Note - I was facing same issue in my terminal. It wasn't opening. So I opened it's config file and changed python 3 to python 3.6

Comment: Did this work??

Comment: Nopes. I am not facing an alias issue. It's that the programs which were fixed up to open with python 3 were actually being opened by python 3.6. Now that I have installed Python 3.7 and pointed my default python 3 to 3.7, I need a way to explicitely tell all Python 3 dependent programs to use Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Make an alias, put it in your ~/.bashrc file or some other alias file you have.

`alias python = python3.7`